# Python script opening wrong file in Atom?

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

Instead of opening all the programs and files one by one to edit my website when I turn on my computer, I want to execute a python script to open them all for me. However, when I run it, it is always opening an index.html file in a folder titled 'index'. I want it to open up say, webpages.html in the 'webpages' folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, webbrowser, subprocess

os.chdir('C:/Users/Bruin/Desktop/My_Webpage')
current_path = os.getcwd()

file_to_open = input('What filename to open?')
print("hello")

#subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\Bruin\AppData\Local\atom\atom.exe', r'C:\Users\Bruin\Desktop\My_Webpage\'' + file_to_open + r'\'' + file_to_open + r'.html'])
subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\Bruin\AppData\Local\atom\atom.exe', r'C:\Users\Bruin\Desktop\My_Webpage\webpages\webpage.html'])

webbrowser.open('file:///C:/Users/Bruin/Desktop/My_Webpage/index/index.html', new=2)
```

I commented out where I used the inputed variable because even explicitly typing in what I want to open directly into the script, it is not working. It is opening up in the browser just fine.

I am also working in PyCharm, do not know if that matters. It didn't work in IDLE either. I'm lost on where to go.

Comment: You probably want `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Comment: @jordanm, that depends on the Python version. Python 3 doesn't _have_ `raw_input()`; its `input()` would be correct.

Comment: Colin, in your hardcoded example the directory and file name aren't the same: `webpages` vs `webpage.html`. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @jordanm yes I am running Python 3

Comment: @Chris I fixed it but it is still the same. I am also wondering if the settings of Atom are interfering with the ability to open the folder and file I want

Comment: @Chris I assumed python2 because the binary in the shebang was `python` and not `python3`.

Comment: @jordanm, as you've discovered that's not a reliable way to determine the Python version. There are plenty of situations where Python 3 might be the default Python.

Comment: @Chris true, but that does go against PEP 394.

Comment: @jordanm, TIL. I've used Arch Linux (where `python` is `python3`) for years, which is identified as the motivation for that PEP. IMO Python 3 should be the default everywhere, but that's a conversation for another place and time. It is interesting that PEP 394 specifically refers to "Unix-Like Systems"; I guess that means that it doesn't apply to Windows systems like the OP is using here.